# how to use XIB with TableView - code ignores the XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a XIB with a Tableview. I assigned the datasource and the delegate to the Files Owner.

```
   List *screen = [[List alloc] initWithNibName:@"List" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.Search = screen;
[screen release];

[mainNavController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

I push the screen using the above.  However it ignores the XIB and it seems to load a generic tableview.  If I omit the initWithNibName part, it works the same as with it.

I assume there must be something I needed to tie the XIB to the code, but not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing the screen before you push it. do this:

```
List *screen = [[List alloc] initWithNibName:@"List" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.Search = screen;

[mainNavController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];

[screen release];
```

Comment: that didnt make any difference ;(

Comment: This is happening b/c you didn't initialize your table right. Is the Files Owner of your table a UITableViewController or a regular UIViewController? And can you pass the code where you initialize your table.

Comment: Files Owner on the table is set to datasource and delegate.  There isnt a TableViewController on the XIB,  There is a View. The view is set to files owner.  I dont think I have an initialize for the table. Maybe thats the problem.  I dont see anywhere where is says use that specific tableview that I have on the XIB.  I would think there would be something that tell it to do that.  So i guess it just creates its own tableview somehow?

Comment: Cyprian's code is correct, [screen release] needs to be after it is passed to the navigation controller. Make sure that in your XIB, you have associated your uitableviewcontroller to your class List class instance. It sounds like you're using a standard uiviewcontroller instance.

Comment: The tableview shows up ok and shows the data that I loaded. It just doesnt seem to care about the xib.  in the xib I told it the name of the class.  I also load the xib when the screen is pushed. should I have made a different class or something? it is loading the table so I thought I must have at least got it close.